# How to remove an old OS from the boot menu

Tags: windows-7, boot

When I upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7, I had a second drive around and set it to dual boot.

After a while, I decided that I wasn't ever going to go back to Windows XP, and so I deleted the windows directory on that drive. Unfortunately, now I can't remove Windows XP from the boot menu.

I tried going into MSCONFIG to the boot tab, but it only lists windows 7.
I don't know if it's still going off of the Windows XP Boot ini.

edit:
Before:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /v

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=D:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {d703a693-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
resumeobject            {d703a692-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
displayorder            {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c}
                        {d703a693-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Legacy OS Loader
------------------------
identifier              {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \ntldr
description             Earlier Version of Windows

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {d703a693-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {d703a694-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {d703a692-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
nx                      OptIn
```

After:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /delete {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c} /f
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /v

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=D:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {d703a693-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
resumeobject            {d703a692-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
displayorder            {d703a693-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {d703a693-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {d703a694-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {d703a692-0587-11df-9a8e-e8a34060eec6}
nx                      OptIn
```

I'll have to wait until later to restart it and test it out though

Comment: So you had Windows XP on HDD 1 and Windows 7 on HDD 2. And then you deleted C:\Windows directory from HDD 1 but you did not format the disk? Now when you boot the computer you see both Windows XP and Windows 7 as options?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. I had stuff on HDD 1 that I wanted to keep, but I wanted to free up the room in Windows and Program Files that weren't going to be used any more.

Comment: Windows 7 normally creates a 100 MB system partition, and its boot information is stored there. Its not on the MBR. So as I said, clear the MBR using fdisk of the XP (HDD1), and boot with the windows 7 (HDD2) by changing it in the BIOS.. it's the simplest solution..

Comment: @aliasgar Correct me if I'm wrong but fdisk is not available in Windows XP. I believe that fdisk was only available in DOS and Windows 95 and 98. On the other hand, even if fdisk was part of Windows XP this user would not be able to use it since he already has deleted the Windows directory. So how do you plan to boot into Windows 7 and... do what?... use fdisk from the Windows XP disk drive?... which is stored where, if Windows directory is already gone?

Comment: i know this is a old story but it popped up pretty high on {famouse search engine}... I want to add that using windows power shell all the {guid} strngs should be put into '...' like '{guid}'.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to manually edit the BCD (Boot Configuration Data) store. To do that, you will have to use a tool called **bcdedit**.

**Export BCD settings for backup**

Start by exporting your current BCD settings for backup.

1. Boot into Windows 7
2. Log in with an administrator account
3. Open up an elevated command prompt
4. Type `bcdedit /export c:\bcdbackup` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will create a file named *bcdbackup* on your C disk. Note that there is no file extension in the file name. No file extension is needed here. You can change this location or the name of the file if you like, but having it stored on the root of C will make it easy to find if needed.

**List all entries in BCD store**

This will return a list of all the operating systems that the computer can boot from.

- Enter `bcdedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Enter `bcdedit /v` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

By using the V switch the list will give you the UUIDs. Here is an example of what it could look like if you only use `bcdedit` without the V (verbose) switch.

[image: bcdedit1]

And here is an example with the V switch.

[image: bcdedit2]

You need to use the V switch to see the UUIDs for the different operating systems.

**Deleting the Windows XP entry**

Do you see any entry for Windows XP on the right side of the *description* headline? If so, then you need to delete it. And to delete it, you need to know its identifier.

The identifier is the UUID number you see on the right side of the *identifier* headline, including the braces. Braces are the curly brackets at the start and the end of the number.

1. If you have not done so yet, type `bcdedit /v` and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Locate the identifier UUID for the entry that has "Windows XP" as
   description.
3. To delete the entry type `bcdedit /delete {UUID}` and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Depending on how many operating systems you have installed, this could take anywhere from 4 minutes to 15 minutes. Just let it do its thing, you will see a confirmation message when it's done.

**Warning!** Make sure you type in the correct UUID! You need to type in the UUID for Windows XP. If you type in the UUID for Windows 7 then you will not be able to boot into Windows 7, at least not until you restore it using the backup file you created earlier.

When you see the confirmation message, type `bcdedit /v` again and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Make sure that there is no entry for Windows XP anymore. Reboot the computer to make sure that you can boot into Windows 7, and that the boot loader is no longer presenting the boot menu. If this is the case then you are all done now.

**How to rebuild an existing BCD store using bootrec**

If you still see the boot menu, or if you are unable to boot into Windows 7, then you will have to do one of two things.

- A: Restore the BCD using the backup file you created earlier (see instructions below).
- B: You can rebuild the BCD using a tool called Bootrec.

To do either one of these things you will need to enter the *System Recovery Options*.

1. Reboot the computer
2. Press and hold the <kbd>F8</kbd> key right after the *POST*, until
   you see the *Advanced Boot Options* menu. The *POST* is the
   power-on-self-test, this is the first screen that appears when you
   start the computer.
3. Select the *Repair Your Computer* option and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should take you to the *System Recovery
   Options*, also known as WinRE (Windows Recovery Environment).

When you get to the *System Recovery Options* click on the *Command Prompt* link to open up a command prompt. To try to rebuild the existing BCD store as it is type `bootrec /rebuildbcd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now it will scan hard disk drives for Windows installations.

If the bootrec finds any Windows installations it will ask you whether or not you want to add it to the boot list. To say yes press <kbd>Y</kbd>, to say no press <kbd>N</kbd>, and to say yes to all press <kbd>A</kbd>. If Windows 7 was previously removed from the boot list then this operation should add it back to the boot list.

**How to rebuild a new BCD store using bootrec**

If the bootrec does not find any Windows installations, then you will have to delete the BCD completely and then run the `bootrec /rebuildbcd` command again and bootrec will create a brand new working BCD store.

The BCD store is located in `C:\Boot`. But instead of deleting the BCD you can also rename it from *BCD* to *BCD.old*. This has the same effect as deleting it - Windows will no longer use it, but the benefit is that you have one extra layer of backup of the BCD. To rename the BCD you will first have to change its attributes.

1. Type `attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> This
   will remove the attributes Hidden, Read-only and System.
2. Type `ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `bootrec /rebuildbcd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> To add found
   Windows installations to the boot list press <kbd>Y</kbd> or
   <kbd>A</kbd> for all. This should create a new BCD file in
   `C:\Boot`. This new file will be different from the old one that was
   previously renamed.

Reboot the computer and see if you are able to boot into Windows 7, and if you get the boot menu. If you don't see the boot menu and you are able to boot into Windows 7 then everything is alright now.

**Import BCD settings from backup**

If you for some reason want to restore your BCD to the backup copy you created earlier you can use the `bcdedit /import c:\bcdbackup` command. You can use this command either from within Windows, or from the WinRE command prompt.

**Reminder**

For the future, make sure to remove the old Windows entry from the boot list before deleting the Windows folder. To do that, you can use the `msconfig` tool, as I'm sure you're familiar with that. It is only after you have removed the boot list entry for the Windows version you plan on removing that you can delete its Windows folder.

I would personally prefer to completely format that disk partition. If you are concerned about your personal files that are still stored on the old disk then you should back them up or simply copy them over to the new disk. It's also a good practice to store personal files on a separate partition. That way you will be able to access them easily from other operating systems.

Comment: I get this: "C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /delete {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c}
This entry cannot be deleted unless the /f switch is specified on the command
line.  Run bcdedit /? for more information.
Access is denied." bcdedit /? doesn't list the /f flag, and it doesn't work if I try putting it in there.

Comment: To get more information about the F switch you can type `bcdedit /delete /?`.

Comment: This is because this entry has a well known identifier, i.e. it is a Windows operating system entry. Can you please confirm, is this indeed the UUID for your Windows XP entry? And are you logged in as an administrator in Windows 7? And you have administrator privileges (elevated command prompt)? If so, then it should be safe to use the F switch.

Comment: If the UUID stated above is indeed your Windows XP entry then you should try the same command with the F switch as suggested by the program. So type `bcdedit /delete {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c} /f` and press Enter.

Comment: I figured it out. I put the /f after /delete the first time. Then I put it after the UUID and it said it worked.

Comment: Of course, syntax is very important. If you use the `bcdedit /delete /?` command you will see that the F switch is actually supposed to come after the UUID. The last switch you could use is the cleanup switch. So `bcdedit /delete {your UUID} /f /cleanup`. Reboot and see if the problem is solved. If this doesn't solve the issue then ultimately you can use the method described above to create a completely new BCD store in WinRE and have the `bootrec /rebuildbcd` re-create all entries. You can also create a BCD store with `bcdedit`but it will be empty and you will have to add everything manually.

Comment: Wont be home to really test it for a while. Thanks for all that. I'd upvote you again if I could for all that typing.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **run** in your start menu, **type msconfig**, hit enter, select **boot tab** find and **highlight the OS** you want to delete then **hit the delete button**.

Comment: "I tried going into MSCONFIG to the boot tab, but it only lists windows 7." OP tried that

Comment: +1 Journeyman, that one is on me. However, I actually just solved the same issue not 2 hours ago by using the method I mentioned above, so I'll leave it there as an additional option for future OPs. I up-voted Sammy for his answer, and for teaching me something in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have done this before, here it is:

1. Go to **`cmd`** or boot with a bootable disk which takes you to command prompt and execute

   > C:> fdisk /mbr

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
2. Reboot.
3. Go into BIOS, and set the Windows 7 Drive to boot before any other drive, and you wont have a bootloader option anymore. It will boot directly into Windows 7

Comment: C:\>fdisk /?
'fdisk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: if your Running it on XP check out this video : http://www.ehow.com/video_4992226_run-fdisk-windows-xp-pro.html
and for additional documentation check : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69013
If you have a windows 98 bootable CD.. boot with CD-ROM support, and that will also run fdisk

Comment: @AndyD273 If you from within Windows 7 command prompt type `fdisk` and press Enter it is normal to get the kind of error you are getting. This is because the `fdisk ` command doesn't exist. As simple as that. Type `help`and press Enter and you will see a complete list of internal commands you can use, and you will not find `fdisk` to be one of them. To check for external commands type `start c:\windows\system32`. This will open the search path in Explorer. Now try to locate `fdisk` and you will not find it. So this is all very normal for Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 98? Use Windows 98 to fix Windows 7? That's like saying use a hammer to fix a rocket launcher. That's one ancient OS. As I understand it the user has Windows 7 installed and working, and this is the one he want to keep.

Comment: That Microsoft article applies to Windows 95, not to Windows 7. You can see that at the bottom of the page. But you can accomplish the same thing with the `bootrec` command in Windows 7 as you would with `fdisk /mbr` in Windows 98 and earlier, or the `fixmbr` in XP. So why not use the `fixmbr` or the `fdisk` command instead?

Comment: I meant why not use the new `bootrec` command insted? Of course to get to it you would need to enter Recovery Environment (WinRE). But it's the same with XP, you need to enter the "Recovery Console". It would be `bootrec /fixmbr` in RE of Vista or Windows 7.

Comment: The idea is to clean the MBR, how i do it doesn't matter, and the MBR doesn't differ from OS to OS.. so ur sarcasm of "using the hammer to fix rocket launcher" does not apply .. sorry to say.. and i can clean the MBR using the linux kernel also.. so ancient or new does the job..

Comment: I know, but it's better to tell him how to use the tools he already has easily available then to tell him to go get a copy of Windows 98 from somewhere or grab some Linux live CD for this task. You know?... you have to consider what tools he has available and his level of knowledge. And Windows XP is obviously not an option for him, now that he has removed the Winodws folder from that disk. Besides, why fix something that's not broken? It's not like he can't boot. He just needs to remove that extra boot option.

Comment: I agree with what you say, and what i suggested was my method. And he should use what is handy and available to him and do what he is comfortable with. It's just that what you commented, and your sarcasm along with it was uncalled for!

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually not sure where I'd get a windows 98 cd from. We skipped from 3.1 -> 95 -> ME -> XP -> 7

Comment: Regarding DOS/9X's fdisk /mbr, Windows XP's equivalent is FIXMBR, also it has FIXBOOT and BOOTCFG /REBUILD, from the XP recovery console.   With an external floppy drive, he could run fdisk /mbr with a win98 boot disk(easily downloadable, @AndyD273 you obviously don't need a cd dude), or XP has a 6 floppy boot set that I think can get to a recovery console(if you have no XP CD). But I like the idea of solving it with Win7 tools. If it was thought to be an XP boot.ini file issue, you can look at it in notepad and even edit it with notepad, just make boot.ini not read only attrib -r boot.ini

Answer (score 2):

I hope that someone else doesn't go through the same pain I did.

If you keep getting the windows boot manager with only one entry, despite still having a 0 second timeout from msconfig, do the following:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no
```

Answer (score 0):

How to remove a second installation of a Windows operating system from a partition

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888023

Remove Ubuntu or XP from the Windows 7 Boot Menu

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17903/remove-ubuntu-or-xp-from-the-windows-7-boot-menu/