# How do I remove Windows that is not Installed?

Tags: boot, windows-10, duplicate

Whenever I boot up my PC I get 2 options:

1. Windows 10 (C:\Windows) - default OS and this is what I use
2. Windows 10 (\Windows) - when I click this, it goes to a blue error screen saying that Windows needs recovery

Why does number 2 show up and how do I cleanly remove it?

Picture for reference:
[image: Picture]

Comment: Probably just a left over from an upgrade or reinstall, etc. Why not just highlight it and hit "Delete"?

Comment: Hi Techie, you're right, I can actually just hit delete. However, I'm posting this question more of curiosity and cleanliness! I want to be as thorough as possible in deleting this.

Comment: I think it's not safe to clean it,  maybe there is registry files or drivers still used.. is there two windows folders when you open C:\ ?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/465342)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to delete it. This information is stored in the boot.ini file in the boot drive (for Windows XP) or in the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) (for Windows 7 and up). The information probably got corrupted during the Windows 10 installation process, but you can remove the bad entry safely.