# Is it safe to format a drive that contains my active boot.ini file?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I've backed up all files and ready to wipe this partition.

[Hopefully my boot.ini file is not included in this... :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLPZS.png)  [I'm currently performing a Select All - Delete as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1jZ2.png) I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, but this was a second install to the original, on bigger physical disk. I believe it boots from the older smaller drive, which currently has a copy of Windows 7 32-bit. After moving all files off that install I'm now ready to format the D:\ drive (it used to be C:\ drive or probably still is if I boot back into 32-bit windows).

Not sure if it matters, but both the old and new disks have been shrunk in order for Linux to be placed on. Small one got Deepin, and the big one, Linux Mint.

As you can see, the C: drive is fresher - the new install of 64 bit.

```
C:\Users\BvSsh_VirtualUsers>dir c:
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-nnnn

 Directory of C:\Users\BvSsh_VirtualUsers

02/08/2016  03:42 a.m.    <DIR>          .
02/08/2016  03:42 a.m.    <DIR>          ..
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Desktop
02/08/2016  03:42 a.m.    <DIR>          Documents
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Downloads
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Favorites
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Links
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Music
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Pictures
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Saved Games
14/07/2009  02:34 p.m.    <DIR>          Videos
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  73,751,502,848 bytes free

C:\Users\BvSsh_VirtualUsers>dir d:
 Volume in drive D is hp110
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-nnnn

 Directory of D:\

11/06/2015  12:54 a.m.             1,024 .rnd
11/06/2009  09:42 a.m.                24 autoexec.bat
11/06/2009  09:42 a.m.                10 config.sys
04/05/2015  12:59 a.m.    <DIR>          cygwin
06/07/2015  07:59 p.m.               383 ftconfig.ini
29/07/2016  05:51 a.m.                91 HaxLogs.txt
24/02/2015  11:37 p.m.    <DIR>          inetpub
12/12/2014  03:04 p.m.    <DIR>          Intel
04/09/2015  12:58 a.m.             7,210 Jumi.Log
11/09/2015  09:22 p.m.           852,343 Jumi.Log.Run
14/07/2009  02:37 p.m.    <DIR>          PerfLogs
25/02/2015  12:00 a.m.    <DIR>          php
29/07/2016  11:49 a.m.    <DIR>          Program Files
02/08/2016  03:30 a.m.    <DIR>          Users
11/02/2016  09:05 p.m.    <DIR>          WCH.CN
03/07/2016  02:05 a.m.    <DIR>          Windows
04/03/2015  11:28 p.m.    <DIR>          xampp
               7 File(s)        861,085 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  59,775,913,984 bytes free

C:\Users\BvSsh_VirtualUsers>
```

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have `boot.ini`. You can format any drive that you didn't boot from, though.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben N points out, OS's prior to Windows vista use boot.ini's. That itself points out its an outdated file!

Given the D:\ drive is now a data drive, not a system drive for you, it is safe to format. If you want to speed up the process, you can reformat the disk straight away rather than doing a select all delete (If your not worried about data security ofcourse.)

Comment: Totally I feel you on this (not needing to select all delete first), and in fact, this is the reason for the format to get rid of those pesky folders that simple won't die. That is a good point about the modern world of NT kernels. So the bootloader does show 3 options after my install (I forgot to add), I assume this will still be there after the format?

Comment: Reading from another super user thread, the option will remain. The top answer of this thread shows you how to use BCD: http://superuser.com/questions/465047/how-to-remove-an-old-os-from-the-boot-menu