# Windows presents many OS during startup, how to remove it?

Tags: windows-10

Long story short:

I have a laptop that, after updating, has an error stating: 
"boot configuration file is missing "

So I used this [method](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/fix-0xc0000034-error-windows-10)

and the laptop was perfect EXCEPT everyday, when the user boots the computer, there are three choices of Operating system which she has to click. DO take note that all these OS are Windows 10 64 bit. My question is, how to get rid of it?

Comment: If you know what you are doing: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/editing-boot-options

Comment: @TNierath Please help me, I cant understand this command...

Comment: Check this out https://superuser.com/questions/465047/how-to-remove-an-old-os-from-the-boot-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open run by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> key shortcut. Type `msconfig` and hit enter. Go To the Boot Tab. Find the OS you want and set it as default OS. Then you can delete other options.

If you not sure what to chose, select one and set it as default, then restart your PC. If the default OS is the right one, then you can remove other options.

[image]

Using Disk Cleanup, you might be able to delete the unnecessary OS files.