# Preventing a downloaded Windows Update to be applied

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1803

I'm in need of preventing the big update of Windows 10 Home Single Language to version 1803, where I failed to stop it, until the state of wait for restart to apply it. I used Wushowhide tool to hide (after that state unfortunately). Disabled Windows Update with [Windows Update Blocker](https://www.sordum.org/9470/windows-update-blocker-v1-1/), which changed the status of Windows Update page, as there's no restart is needed. After that, I tried these commands below on Windows PowerShell:

- `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` (not successful)
- `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /spsuperseded` (not successful)
- `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` (not changed anything, I suppose)
- `DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` (took time to complete, but still there are too much files on c:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\ as listed here: https://app.box.com/s/od6cu0ibgkmmhncbbrzl9qnh472rdi0d I suppose it also changed nothing.)

As anyone can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6870.png), EasyBCD still shows a second entry. How shall I remove that? Just by deleting it? Also, $WINDOWS.~BT and $Windows.~WS directories are there to finish the update process.

I really appreciate any help anyone can provide as quickly as he/she can.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/465047) that has approximately similar procedure.